# How to set up ktor logging in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, ktor

`project:build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false    
}
```

`app:build.gradle`

```
def ktor_version = "2.2.4"
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-cio:$ktor_version")
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version"
implementation 'io.ktor:ktor-client-logging:$ktor_version'
implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation:$ktor_version"
```

Set it up like in the docs:

```kotlin
val instance = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(Logging) {
      logger = Logger.DEFAULT
      level = LogLevel.HEADERS
      filter { request ->
        request.url.host.contains("ktor.io")
      }
    }    
  }
```

but I get the error(At least, that's what I think):

```
W/System.err: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
W/System.err: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
W/System.err: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

1. I checked some information, added the following dependency:

```
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-logging-jvm:$ktor_version")
```

it's not working, same error.

2. I added another dependency:

```
implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.5'
```

Then a new error appeared:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 2 files found with path 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST' from inputs:
      - D:\Software\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-classic\1.4.5\28e7dc0b208d6c3f15beefd73976e064b4ecfa9b\logback-classic-1.4.5.jar
      - D:\Software\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ch.qos.logback\logback-core\1.4.5\e9bb2ea70f84401314da4300343b0a246c8954da\logback-core-1.4.5.jar
     Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
     https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.4/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions
     for more information
```

I'm not quite sure what this `greadle cache` is for. But logically, I'm pretty sure that my project didn't introduce `logback` related dependencies before `ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.5` was added.

1. So after I introduced `logback`, it caused its own error? This is illogical, what am I missing?
2. Do I really need `ktor-client-logging`? What exactly does it do? I am using it on the `Android` platform. Will it print the result of each request?

Comment: Can you try to use the `org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.7.36` SLF4J Android Binding library instead of the `logback-classic`?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman It worked for me. By the way, how can I be sure that `Log` is in effect, after sending a request, I don't see the relevant logs about `ktor` being printed?

Comment: You should see logs in Logcat with the `HttpClient` search string.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Thanks, it works perfectly fine now. I realized that I missed setting the request filter in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add
`debugImplementation "org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.7"`